# pip install . vs setup.py: final directory

Tags: python, pip

I have a `setup.py` looking like

```
setup(name='foo',
      py_modules=['bar'],
      ext_modules=[Extension('lib.api', ['lib/api.c'])]
     )
```

`python setup.py install --user` bundles it into
`~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/foo-0.0.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/`

However, running `pip install . --user` does not generate a parent directory, but messes everything directly in `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`. When having more modules, it will become confusing.

Why they behave differently? And how can I get `pip` to use a parent directory?

Comment: I believe that's the normal behavior. It shouldn't get confusing, why do you think so?

Comment: It appears less ordered. And if there is another package with a `lib` folder, it will write in to the same folder and maybe even overwrite `api.so`.

Comment: If you want a directory — create a package (importable directory with `__init__.py`) and use `packages=['…']` instead of `py_modules`.

Comment: If there are modules or packages with the same name, there will be problems anyway. Either one of them will get overwritten or only one of them will be importable. So from my point of view, better have everything in one directory, then it will become immediately clear if there is a name clash.